# n-n relationships for multiple content types

Tags: laravel-backpack

I'm working on a project based on Laravel 5.3 and Backpack CRUD. My project has about 8 different content types (news, page, portfolio, events, team, video, gallery, jobs).

I need to be able to add tags to every content type (n-n), and every content type has its own specific tags, so tags are NOT shared between the content types.

If I want to use the select_multiple or select2_multiple field type, I would need 8 tables for the content itself, 8 pivot tables, and 8 tables for the tags(!).

Obviously I would like to have just one table for the tags, but if I use the select_multiple or select2_multiple field type, I get all tags in the edit-form of every content type.

So, my question is: Is there an elegant way to filter the results of the select_multiple or select2_multiple field type?

I have created a simple schema with two content types:
http://dbdesigner.net/designer/schema/60412

In this example I want to be able to filter the tag list on content_type_id, when I'm editing the content of news or page. So I just want to see the news tags in the news-edit form, and just the page tags, in the page-edit form.

Or maybe I should just use the select_multiple field type as intended, and accept the 8 tag tables(?)

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think a clean way would be to:

- create different models for each tag use, so `NewsTag`, `PageTag`, `PortfolioTag` etc. that would only extend the `Tag` model and use a [global scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#global-scopes) to filter the results after `content_type_id`;
- use backpack select2_multiple fields with `NewsTag`, `PageTag`, `PortfolioTag` etc; anything you set on the `Tag` model will be used (including the `table` attribute, mutators, accessors, etc);

Cheers!